# How to check MD5/SHA1 of iso?

Tags: iso, dvd

How do I check the MD5 and SHA1 of an ISO file? It's a Windows 7 iso.

Comment: The settings likely have nothing to do with the errors. Parts of the ISO might get corrupted while it's been downloaded. You need to check the ISO itself to make sure the hashsum matches.

Comment: Yeah, you need to check the MD5/SHA1 of the ISO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `md5sum` command, example:

```
md5sum MY_FILE.iso
```

And the same for SH1, with `sha1sum` command, example:

```
sha1sum MY_FILE.iso
```

Comment: I did that but how can I verify that that's the right md5/sh1?

Comment: Compare the hash that your machine calculated with the corresponding hash on the website where you downloaded the file from