# Issue with Mythbuntu downloads?

Tags: mythbuntu

Is Mythbuntu no longer downloadable?

All of the iso downloads I have attempted ended up being Gparted live isos,

I downloaded the desktop image for 16.04 .1 and .3 and 14.04 .5
I downloaded directly and attempted the torrent for a couple, but when I burn the .iso it is actually Gpated

Comment: Where are you attempting to obtain Mythbuntu? what is the full name of the ISO you obtained and it's [md5sum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845836/how-to-check-md5-sha1-of-iso)

Comment: I will take anoter look this weekend, but

I have directly downloaded the following from the Ubuntu image site
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/16.04/release/ , 

but when I burn them to dvd with k3b they are gParted. 
k3b runs a checksum and passes, but I have not verified myself.
 

 mythbuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso

    mythbuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
    mythbuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
    mythbuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
    mythbuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

    mythbuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso

 also used torrent for a couple of them

Comment: A cannot reproduce your problem which leads me to believe that this is user error rather than a problem with the image. If I download th mythbuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso the k3b md5sum matches and when I boot it, I get Mythbuntu. Are you labeling your disks?

Comment: Thank you Elder, I will attempt booting the disks on another machine. The particular box I am booting to is Windows 10 and I wonder if it has something to do with UEFI, but it is odd that the discs boot to gParted live.

Answer (score 0):

Mythbuntu is still available from [Mythbuntu releases on the cdimage server.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/) If you are having trouble with torrents, consider [downloading the 16.04.3 ISO directly](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/16.04.3/release/) and verifying that you have a good copy by [**checking the hash.**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/845836/how-to-check-md5-sha1-of-iso)

Here's a list of md5sums from the cdimage server:

```
1d24bbcc83f18069cd9f7562271181fb *mythbuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso
153569d8fb6ac05881b5876df04f440a *mythbuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso
33d0dcd7b9da6adc2ed8da4c1a59b0aa *mythbuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
bd19ae5151e484c692baa9489952621c *mythbuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
ba6518b77a4db6db899d370bedf2356c *mythbuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
4038c9a02a7c58c51f2febc5d38f04c1 *mythbuntu-16.04.2-desktop-i386.iso
eff5e3e9f33e8cdcea40d603ad08bc39 *mythbuntu-16.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
64232638e1e88f893a6754666174e73c *mythbuntu-16.04.3-desktop-i386.iso
```

You might also find [this related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/503776/md5-hash-for-ubuntu-iso-14-04-through-17-04/503788) useful. You can also find the SHA1SUMS and SHA256SUMS [here.](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/16.04.3/release/)

Comment: Thank you, I will give it another shot this weekend. 

I have downloaded the iso for "or 16.04 .1 and .3 and 14.04 .5 I downloaded directly and attempted the torrent for a couple", but when I burn the image to dvd using k3b the image is actually gParted